# Updating image using interface

Tags: android, interface

I have a fragment which I am using to update a profile picture in my App. The profile picture is in navigation header. When the new profile picture is successfully uploaded to the server I am calling interface method in home activity to update the profile picture. The method is getting called but the picture is not being updated. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Interface 


public interface UpdateProfilePicture {

        void updateDp();
}

// method calling after successful uploading of picture

val updateDp = activity as UpdateProfilePicture
                                    updateDp.updateDp()


//Overriding method in home activity
     override fun updateDp() {
            Log.e("Changing profile ","Profile picture change user home activity " +"http://console.salelinecrm.com/saleslineapi/GetprofileImage/" + objSaveData.getString(ConstantValue.USER_ID));


            Picasso.with(baseContext)
                        .load("http://console.salelinecrm.com/saleslineapi/GetprofileImage/" + objSaveData.getString(ConstantValue.USER_ID))
                        .into(imageView);
        }
```

Comment: Is it is synchronise request ?

Comment: It is an asynchronous  request